Bayes' Theorem applied in real study
My name is Molly, and I am a medical student at Queens. I'm delving into the realm of statistics. It's essential to comprehend how statistical methods are utilized in medical screening and diagnostics. One crucial area where statistics plays a pivotal role is in prenatal screening for conditions such as Down syndrome. This is my initial step to get in touch with a real case study. Please provide some feedback if anything is wrong.
Understanding the 1:39 Risk Ratio in Down Syndrome Screening
The 1:39 risk ratio in a Down syndrome screening report means that out of 39 pregnant women who have been screened, 1 is expected to have a baby with Down syndrome. This ratio is an estimated relative risk, not an absolute probability. Specifically, 1:39 means the probability of the fetus having Down syndrome is approximately 1/39, which is about 2.56%.
Detailed Explanation

Relative Risk:

A risk ratio of 1:39 indicates that out of 39 women with a positive screening result, one is likely to have a baby with Down syndrome.
This ratio translates to a percentage: 1/39 ≈ 2.56%.


Screening Result Interpretation:

This result is used by healthcare providers to decide whether further diagnostic testing, such as amniocentesis or non-invasive prenatal testing (NIPT), is necessary.


Application of Bayes' Theorem:

While the 1:39 risk ratio provides a preliminary assessment, Bayes' Theorem combines prior probability (initial probability before screening) and the characteristics of the test (false positive rate and false negative rate) to update the probability of having the condition.



Combining the Screening Report and Bayes' Theorem

The screening report provides an initial risk ratio (e.g., 1:39).
Bayes' Theorem is used to refine this estimate by considering the prior probability and the test's accuracy.

Example Calculation

Interpreting the 1:39 Risk Ratio:

A 1:39 risk ratio means there is an approximate 2.56% chance of the fetus having Down syndrome (1/39).


Using Bayes' Theorem for Actual Probability:

Assume the prior probability is 0.1% (1/1000), the false positive rate is 5%, and the false negative rate is 1%.
Using Bayes' Theorem, the posterior probability (actual probability after considering the screening result) is approximately 1.94%.



Summary

Screening Report: Provides an initial risk estimate (e.g., 1:39).
Bayes' Theorem: Refines this estimate by incorporating prior probability and test characteristics to provide a more accurate probability.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This looks like a homework problem (correct me if I am wrong) which have their own guidelines. Here are some hints.
You write:

This ratio is an estimated relative risk, not an absolute probability.
Specifically, 1:39 means the probability of the fetus having Down
syndrome is approximately 1/39, which is about 2.56%.

The second sentence contradicts the first.
The risk ratio is a ratio of risks in two groups. You haven't said what the groups are. Are you comparing screened women to unscreened women?

Also to fully solve the problem you would need to have a model in continuous mother’s age for the probability that her baby has the syndrome.  The becomes the ‘prevalence’ in Bayes’ formula.  Having a non-age-specific prevalance would not be very using.

Thanks for your reply. Would you like to tell me more about this,like mother's age? 1:39 is from a report,but i did not find the detail useful information,or it might be missing data.Thanks for your support.

sorry for the confusion.  1:39 is from a prenatal report and indicates the risk ratio for Down syndrome. The 1.94% is calculated using Bayes' theorem to estimate the actual probability that a pregnant woman with a positive screening result will have a baby with Down syndrome.

Risk ratio of what?  That is, it has to be a ratio of two things. It might be screened vs. not screened, but it might be something else.
